# why does this prolog code return only one result?

Tags: prolog

I'm studying Prolog for a final exam, and I can't figure out what I did wrong on this assignment question from early in the course.

This isn't exactly a 'homework' question, it's a 'studying for the final question' so if someone can give me a correct answer, it would be a great help. :(

The question was:

```
%% b) Write a predicate after(X, List, Result) that returns everything 
%% in a list after any occurrence of the given element X.
%% ?- after(a,[b,a,x,d,a,f,g],R).
%% R = [x,d,a,f,g];
%% R = [f,g];
%% no
```

My solution was this, but it only returns one value for R, not two.

```
after(X,[_,X|R],R).

?- after(a,[b,a,x,d,a,f,g],R).
R = [x, d, a, f, g].
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code also doesn't work for the element being anywhere but the second position, e.g., `after(a,[a,b,c],R).` does not work. Think about how to solve it in a generic manner and you'll probably end up getting multiple results as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hours on this and figured it out as soon as I posted it here!

Just FYI, here's my solution:

```
after(X,[X|R],R).
after(X,[_|Z],R) :-
    after(X,Z,R).
```